# bin/bash nested loop does not work

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I currently working as a intern at a hosting firm. They asked me to write a bin/bash script to help automate a process to check the user's domain's and .pointers for them. And validate with a "whois" command if the domains/pointers are on our server's.

I'm new with bin/bash scripting but i was told i should check nested loops out. So to test my script out i made similar paths as they would look like on the server. `/usr/local/directadmin/data/users/#USER#/domains.list` and `users/#USER#/domains/#DOMAIN NAME OF USER#.pointers`

```
#part 1 
for i in $(cat /home/MrC/Desktop/Users)  #<the list of users i need to check)
do
    if [ -f "/usr/local/directadmin/data/users/$i/domainlist.txt" ]
    then
        echo "/usr/local/directadmin/data/users/$i" >> /home/MrC/Desktop/output.tx$
        cat "/usr/local/directadmin/data/users/$i/domainlist.txt" >> /home/carlos/Des$
    fi

    #part 2 
    for s in $(cat /home/mrC/Desktop/output.txt)
    do
        if  [ -f "/usr/local/directadmin/data/users/$i/domains/$s.pointers" ]
        then
            echo "/usr/local/directadmin/data/users/$i" >> /home/MrC/Desktop/pointers.$
            cat "usr/local/directadmin/data/users/$i/domains/$s.pointers" >> /home/MrC$
        fi
    done

done
```

So part 1 works this is the output.txt below

```
    /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/testuser
    lolla.nl
    blaat2.nl
    blaat3.nl
    google2.nl
    /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/testusers
    blaat.nl
    google.com
    test.nl
    pietje.nl
```

But i cant seem part two to work (no pointer file). my goal with part two of the script is to read the output (domainname) and put it `@/$i/domains/$s.pointers`.

I'm new on the forum i hope i asked my question in a proper fashion. if some one could give me hints/tips to which direction i should look that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity where did you learn to do `for in in $(cat filename)` ?

Comment: people at work :)

Comment: Don't listen to them any longer... `while read -r i; do #stuff; done < /home/MrC/Desktop/Users` (adjust `IFS` or specify the delimiter with the `-d` option to `read`).

Comment: Cheers, as mentioned it's not really the best way to read files since it is open to lots of "bugs" in that it allows the shell to interpret the line. WRT your question It isn't entirely clear to me your intentions. Would you be able to provide example input and output data?

Comment: Input data is just simply a .txt file with a list of user's example:
user1
user2
user3
output.txt is what a wrote above
my intention is just simply check a list of given users. and then write their domains and .pointers below. All users have their own directory of course. user: mrc. domain=mr-c.com so the .pointer text file is being called:mr-c.pointers

Comment: so my ideal situation would be something like this
/usr/local/directadmin/data/users/testuser
    lolla.nl
    blaat2.nl
    blaat3.nl
    google2.nl
/usr/local/directadmin/data/users/testuser/pointers
pointer1
pointer2
pointer 3

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin cheers mate. Helped me alot

Comment: Glad it helped. Drop another comment if you are still stuck, but I figured with the comments (from all), you were pretty much pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
For
   Do
     if
      then
for
   do
    COMMAND A
    COMMAND B
    COMMAND C

   done
   fi
done
```

Comment: Make your answer more likely by adding some explanation along with the code.

Comment: this is the format of a correct nested loop i thought it was self explanatory. It did not work because i had **fi** on the wrong position

Answer (score 0):

`while read -r i; do #stuff; done < /home/MrC/Desktop/Users` (adjust `IFS` or specify the delimiter with the `-d` option to `read`).
                    – David C. Rankin